# Module build failed - React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm following some video tutorial on react and now I'm stuck with this "module build failed error". The screenshots are provided below, Some invalid index.js having invalid property of 'name'.

Please check them and help me out, webpack is showing error though in video 
tutorial they had no errors!

[//webpack.config.js//](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fyt2G.png)

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './public/app.jsx',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './public/bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
 extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
 },
  module: {
loaders: [
  {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
      presets: ['react', 'es2015']
    },
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

[//package.json//](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WidB.png)

```
{
 "name": "hello-react",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "simple app\u001b[D\u001b[D\u001b[Dreact app",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
 },
 "author": "Shubham",
 "license": "MIT",
 "dependencies": {
   "express": "^4.15.4",
   "react": "^0.14.7",
   "react-dom": "^0.14.7"
  },
 "devDependencies": {
   "babel-core": "^6.5.1",
   "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
   "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
   "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
   "webpack": "^1.12.13"
 }
}
```

Comment: can you post a link to video?

Comment: When it says it's in index.js, we probably (for sure) need that file too.

Comment: I added the screenshots, but it's not showing here

Comment: @Larce how to get that index.js?

Comment: show us the app.js

Comment: //app.js//

var greeter= require('./components/Greeter');

greeter();

@abdul

Comment: @CaptEmulation 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0Y_Kvdc-YpRdkg1aG11Q2Q2ckE/view

Comment: also post the error message from webpack build

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?